# Algolia React default value and operation problem

Tags: reactjs, algolia

I'm using Algolia for autocomplete inside my React app. But I encountered a few problems during development:

1. The autocomplete already has standard hits if I don't type anything in, how can I turn it off?
2. How can I minimize the operations because now 1 character cost 1 operation, maybe with a type delay?

I'm using the `algoliasearch/lite` and `react-instantsearch-dom`package.

Comment: can you name the package you are using for this?

Comment: `algoliasearch/lite` and `react-instantsearch-dom`

Comment: Did you manage to fix your issues?

Comment: @SamuelVaillant No :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. From the example code in [documentation](https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-reference/widgets/autocomplete/react/?language=component) you can check ther the search box is empty or not. Then render the hits only if `currentRefinement` is not empty:

```
    

import { connectAutoComplete } from 'react-instantsearch-dom';

const Autocomplete = ({ hits, currentRefinement, refine }) => (
  <ul>
    <li>
      <input
        type="search"
        value={currentRefinement}
        onChange={event => refine(event.currentTarget.value)}
      />
    </li>

    //Render only if currentRefinement not empty
    {currentRefinement && (
        hits.map(hit => (
          <li key={hit.objectID}>{hit.name}</li>
        ))
    )}

  </ul>
);

const CustomAutocomplete = connectAutoComplete(Autocomplete);
```

2. Debouncing can achived by using `SearchBox` example code the [documentation](https://www.algolia.com/doc/guides/building-search-ui/going-further/improve-performance/react/#debouncing)

Answer (score 0):

1. React InstantSearch doesn't provide this option out-of-the-box. You have to implement your version of the `searchClient` to abort the request on the empty state. You can find a guide within the [documentation](https://www.algolia.com/doc/guides/building-search-ui/going-further/conditional-requests/react/).
2. You cannot have this behavior out-of-the-box. You can implement it by yourself though. This pattern is called debouncing. There is also a dedicated section about that within the [documentation](https://www.algolia.com/doc/guides/building-search-ui/going-further/improve-performance/react/#debouncing).